# Efficient way to create video from looped .gif file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, gif

I have two files: `animation.gif` and `audio.mp3`; duration(`audio.mp3`) >> duration(`animation.gif`). I want to create `.webm` file from the two, i.e. looped (unknown number of times) `animation.gif` + `audio.mp3`.

A simple (or, at least, obvious), but slow way to create that is:

```
ffmpeg -ignore_loop 0 -i animation.gif -i audio.mp3 -shortest -c:v libvpx -threads 4 -b:v 400k -f webm out.webm
```

So, the question: are there any tricks to speed that up?   Is there a faster way to create a long video from looped `animation.gif`?